# Endogeneity and Consistency

Tags: regression, linear, consistency, endogeneity

So I learned about the endogeneity problem of linear regression in class today, where E[XU] and Cov[X,U] isn't equal to zero but some random constant c times a standard basis k-element vector with 1 as the last element and 0 everywhere else.

This is for a linear regression y = X'B+U and the professor asked us what E[XX']E[XY] is identifying and whether the regression will give out a consistent estimate of B, which made me sort of confused.

If the 0 assumptions aren't satisfied, then wouldn't beta not be identifiable? Is the above matrix now identifying something else or is there some assumption about the X's so that all the betas for the other k-1 covariates can be consistently estimated?